# jQuery Ajax: how to specify different div to update

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'd like to put something on the first line of an Ajax's returned data to specify which div to update. A hypothetical example is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submitForm').ajaxForm({
    success: function(returnData) {
      if (firstLineOf(returnData) == 'firstDiv')
          $('#firstDiv').html(returnData(restOfLines));
      else if (firstLineOf(returnData) == 'secondDiv')
          $('#secondDiv').html(returnData(restOfLines));
      else
          $('#thirdDiv').html(returnData(restOfLines)); 
    }
  });
});
```

How do I do it?

Comment: json and each loop would be way to go...

Comment: You could send back a JSON encoded object with two properties: `targetElement` and `content`. Read the `targetElement` property to know which element to update. Structured data is easier to process than unstructured data. How to create the JSON depends on the server side language you are using.

Comment: I am using python on Google App Engine.

Comment: This might help then: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google+app+engine+json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some code sample for your need

Assume your JSON is

```
[{"targetElement":"div1","HtmlContent":"<div>inner html</div>"}]
```

jQuery is

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submitForm').ajaxForm({
    success: function(returnData) {
      $(returnData.targetElement).html(returnData.HtmlContent)
    }
  });
});
```

Hope this would help you!

Comment: I am not familiar with json. Suppose I use a render function in several places in my program with different message contents supported by a template system: render(self, 'login-message.html', {'message': 'wrong id or password'}), render(..., {'message': 'type both id and password'}), etc. Difference message will be used to update difference div. The actual returned data comes from different files: 'login-message.html', ... Then how do I create the json?